# How to dynamically change combobox on other combobox value change

Tags: c#, winforms, linq-to-sql, combobox

Running a project with linq to sql model, and binding my combos to bindingsource controls, I have two comboBoxes, first shows a table which shows database tables names (ID, TableName) and the second should be bound to the selected table in the first combo, I tried this code:

```
        private void ComboBox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (ComboBox1.Text == "Customers")
        {
            var qry = (from u in dc.Customers
                       select u).ToList();
            comboBox2.ValueMember = "CustomerID";
            comboBox2.DisplayMember = "CompanyName";
            comboBox2.DataSource = qry;
        }
        if (ComboBox1.Text == "Suppliers")
        {
            var qry = (from u in dc.Suppliers
                       select u).ToList();
            comboBox2.ValueMember = "SupplierID";
            comboBox2.DisplayMember = "CompanyName";
            comboBox2.DataSource = qry;
        }
    }
```

With the code above I can show the first combo items, I can show also the second combo items by default, but when I change the first combo content I get error at                 comboBox2.ValueMember = "SupplierID"; : System.ArgumentException was unhandled
  Message=Link to the new Value member impossible. Please how can I reset the combobox2.ValueMember to the new field name?

Comment: Please tell me the fields inside dc.Suppliers the error is throw n because Suppliers does not have SupplierID in it

Comment: Supplier have SupplierID field, you can verify that on Northwind database sample.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is necessary to initialize the combobox properties before changing its ValueMember, like this:

```
        **comboBox2.DataSource = null;**
        if (ComboBox1.Text == "Customers")
        {
            var qry = (from u in dc.Customers
                       select new { u.CustomerID, u.CompanyName }).ToList();
            comboBox2.ValueMember = "CustomerID";
            comboBox2.DisplayMember = "CompanyName";
            comboBox2.DataSource = qry;
        }
        if (ComboBox1.Text == "Suppliers")
        {
            var qry = (from u in dc.Suppliers
                       select new { u.SupplierID, u.CompanyName }).ToList();
            comboBox2.ValueMember = "SupplierID";
            comboBox2.DisplayMember = "CompanyName";
            comboBox2.DataSource = qry;
        }
```

Comment: You are initializing the DataSource in your answer instead of ValueMember

Comment: Yes because initializing DataSource initializes binding properties of combobox.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to return only the columns for ValueMember & DisplayMember

```
var qry = (from u in dc.Suppliers
            select new { a.SupplierID, a.CompanyName}).ToList();
            comboBox2.ValueMember = "SupplierID";
            comboBox2.DisplayMember = "CompanyName";
            comboBox2.DataSource = qry;
```

Comment: Same issue, I think this is a problem related to the combo setting not related to the query. May be we have to reset the property ValueMember to nothing before rebind the combobo2.